# Anylogic: How to add a variable on agent based on a parameter of its upper agent?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

EX:

I have a population `people` with agent type `Person` with a parameter `wrist_size`.

In the agent type `Person` I've created another population =`watches`, agent type =`Watch`.

Now I want to create a variable in the lower agent type that will be based on the parameter of the upper agent.

`length` of the `watch` should be equal to the `wrist_size` of the `person`

What should code should I put to the variable?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `people.wrist_size` in the "initial value" field of `Watch.length`.

Each embedded population (here `Watch` within `Person`) gets a "link" up to their parent agent (here `Person` named `people`).

See https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to for understanding model hierarchies.